# Page Numbers on Existing Patents

Tags: patent-applications, patent-search

I'm filing nonprovisional utility patent and trying to fill out the Information Data Sheet with the related art.  It requires page numbers.  I've looked both on Google Patents and the USPTO's Full Text & Image Database and I'm not finding page numbers.  Where should I be looking???

Comment: Where exactly does it require that?

Comment: @DonQuiKong in updated_IDS.pdf at the USPTO's website, in each of the US Patents, US Patent Application Publications, and Foreign Patents tables, there's a column on the right for Pages, Columns, Lines where Relevant Passages or Relevant Figures appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a hard requirement to include page numbers and current paranoid practice says to not include page numbers. It it turns out that something on a page that was not enumerated has something very relevant you can be accused of intentionally misleading the examiner.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to mention relevant prior art. The page numbers field is to indicate relevant portions of the prior art.

E.g. patent us123456789 A1 page 1, paragraphs 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13

Paper abcdef pages 1 to 22.

Don't over think it, you need to disclose what you know, not provide a full analysis of the prior art.

Leave it blank if you don't know any specially relevant portions.